# MPMoviePlayerController cannot be removed using removeFromSuperView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to remove a MPMoviePlayerController from a View. 
I tried this.

```
[moviePlayerController stop];
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

the video stops, but the view is not removed. I guess `[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];` does not work. What could be the reason ? Any Solution to this prolem ..?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the code related to adding the moviePlayer to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem generally occurs because of the player get deallocated.The solution is that declare the player instance in .h with property "strong".

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController* mpController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a known problem that id you are using ARC, then you HAVE TO add the player to your .h because it does still get released if you declare it locally.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController* controller;
```

To add the view:

```
self.controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:YOURVIDEOURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.controller];

self.controller.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.controller.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];
[self.controller setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

And then to remove the view:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

}

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];

if ([player
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but since I had the problem of the movieplayer not showing up because of auto deallocating, I guess you could just set `moviePlayerController = nil;`.

Not Totally sure if the view will disappear, but worth a try!

Comment: Don't you have to have the movieController inside of a view? Try `[viewContainingMovieController removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissViewController:animated:   That will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[moviePlayerController stop];
[moviePlayerController setContentURL:nil];
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

this is running well in my project

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried all of these:

`[moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer setContentURL:nil];
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
        moviePlayer = nil;`

And nothing worked. I figured out it had to due with my MPMoviePlayerController entering full screen. The fix?

```
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```